# HTML textarea: slightly extended functionality

Tags: html, textarea, styling, rte

In a web application I am developing, I need a slightly extended functionality for a HTML textarea: I can let users click items in a list so they appear in the textarea, but I want these things to be a single stylable "object" with its own color in this textarea.

For example, the list contains something that looks like this : `<--test-->`. In the textarea, this needs to be stylable (color, bold, border, etc...) Also it would be nice if the user deletes one character of this, the entire word gets deleted.

What would be the best thing to use, beside a fully functional RTE? Some JQuery simulated textarea would be nice.

Edit: IE8 support required at least

Comment: If you need the "list" to be hand-editable (otherwise I guess you wouldn't want a `<textarea>` at the first place), try a `<div contenteditable>`.

Comment: @Passerby unfortunately I don't think I can use HTML5. Unless this is supported in IE8?

Comment: It's supported in IE8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533690(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ might help if you need anything that isn't supported in terms of HTML5